# C++ I'm getting expected ‘;’ before '\xa' from g++ 4.4.3 from this code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

   using namespace std;


   int main()
   {
      // char[20] name = "blah";
       int ssn = 123456789;
      int dob = 12742;
      cout << ssn '\n';
      cout << dob'\n';
          return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please put more effort into your question. For example, try to explain your problem in more detail, and click on the 10101 button to properly indent your code. Also remove the line numbers.

Comment: I hear that the cppOverflow site has a  question linking to this one, which includes "WFT"

Answer (score 10):

You need to change:

```
cout << ssn '\n';
cout << dob'\n';
```

to:

```
cout << ssn << '\n';
cout << dob << '\n';
```

The following code is the complete program (as I would write it without the `using`):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int ssn = 123456789;
    int dob = 12742;
    std::cout << ssn << std::endl;
    std::cout << dob << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
123456789
12742
```

Comment: You really should use `std::endl` instead of `'\n'`. Newline isn't guaranteed to be just `'\n'`, it can be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: That's not what endl does. "\n" -> "\r\n" translation is done if necessary and if the file is opened in non-binary mode when the iostreams library sees a newline. endl outputs a newline and flushes the stream, it is equivalent to `'\n' << std::flush`. You definitely should not mindlessly use `endl` anywhere you'd use a `'\n'`, many times it does not make sense to flush prematurely.

Comment: @Logan, that's interesting and one more of the vast ocean of things I still needed to learn about C++ :-) I'm assuming it's okay in this little snippet since efficiency isn't a prime concern, but it's good to know for future reference.

Comment: @Logan: 99.9% of the time, the output is line buffered in any case, which means using either form will produce the exact same results.

Comment: Actually, @Billy, I'm not sure that's quite right. Based on Logan's comment, the `endl` appears to be _preventing_ efficient buffering (i.e., forcing a flush to happen regardless). There's a big difference (in performance rather than functionality) between writing out every 4K buffer and writing out every line.

Comment: @pax: Yes, `std::endl` forces a buffer flush. OTOH, in most standard libraries outputing any sort of `\n` is also going to force a buffer flush. If it did not, you'd not see any text after writing a line.

Comment: @Billy, don't know specifically about C++ but I know that ISO C states something like 'line-flushing is only activated if the output device can be detected as an interactive device'. In that case, using `testprog >/tmp/junk` wouldn't use line buffering (and rightly so for efficiency). But I suspect you're right in this case, the output would most likely be interactive.

Comment: The buffering thing was sort of a side note. Really, I just didn't want anyone to have the mistaken belief that endl was somehow more portable than '\n'. Even if "99.9% of the time" it makes no difference, it's important to know why that is, and actively decide to do one thing or the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << ssn '\n';
cout << dob'\n';
```

It should be:

```
cout << ssn << '\n';
cout << dob << '\n';
```

Also consider using `using std::cout` instead of `using namespace std;`. Including the entire std namespace is usually frowned upon by most C++ programmers.

Comment: "using namespace" declarations cause problems in header files, but there is nothing wrong with using them in cpp files. Especially in an example posted online.

Answer (score 1):

Missing an operator:

```
cout << ssn << endl;
cout << dob << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

However the following is legal in C++ (adjacent string literals)

```
int main() 
{ 
   //char name[20] = "blah"; // the commented array declaration was not correct.

   cout << "blah""\n"; 
   //            ^ no << operator
   return 0; 
}
```